# Delete list element from a pop up button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a list, in which when I click the `li` element, a modal pops up and it has an archive button. So when I click that button, that particular `li` from which the modal came, disappears (display:none). Below is my code -

List

```
<ul>
    <li id="wa" onclick="openModal(this.id)"> List one</li>
    <li id="wb" onclick="openModal(this.id)"> List two</li>
</ul>
```

Modal Window (when I click the list this modal window appears, the css for this modal is not included) -

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal_content" id="modal_content">
        <div class="m_header"><p id="m_header_title"></p> <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none'">&#x2715;</span></div>
        <div class="m_footer">
                <button class="archive" onclick="archive()">Archive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS for modal open -

```
function openModal(id_got){
    var modalOpen = document.getElementById('modal');
    modalOpen.style.display = "block";
    var i = id_got;
    var getId = this.document.getElementById(i);
    var modalHeader = this.document.getElementById('m_header_title');
    modalHeader.innerHTML = getId.innerHTML;
}
```

So, If the click the first `li` with `id="wa"` the modal appears and when I click the archive button, the `li` with `id="wa"` should disappear (display:none).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the `openModal` save the current opened element id in a global variable

```
currentOpened = id_got;
```

then create an handler for the closing event

```
var currentOpened; // global variable

function openModal(id_got){
    var modalOpen = document.getElementById('modal');
    modalOpen.style.display = "block";
    var i = id_got;
    currentOpened = id_got; // here's the add
    var getId = this.document.getElementById(i);
    var modalHeader = this.document.getElementById('m_header_title');
    modalHeader.innerHTML = getId.innerHTML;
}

function onModalClose() {
    document.getElementById(currentOpened).style.display = 'none;
}
```

while the modal html

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal_content" id="modal_content">
        <div class="m_header"><p id="m_header_title"></p> <span class="close" onclick="onModalClose()">&#x2715;
    </span></div>
        <div class="m_footer">
            <button class="archive" onclick="archive()">Archive</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that's it

Comment: hi, @FeMachine, can you please provide the full js code, I am little new to javascript. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you open the modal, save the id in a global variable like

```
active_li = id_got;
```

and when you click to archive your li, in your method you do that :

```
function archive(){
    /*
    do your stuff
    */
    document.getElementById(active_li).style.display = 'none';           
}
```